# Action mailer Development Envrionment Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

So it seems as if I always run into an issue when setting up a mailer in development mode, I cant see anything wrong with my setup, maybe someone else can see something? At the moment when i send an email via my contact form there is no redirect and the params of the email get passed via the url and the same page gets rendered

```
http://localhost:3000/contact?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=123456exampletoken%3D&message%5Bname%5D=richard+lewis&message%5Bemail%5D=richlewis14%40gmail.com&message%5Bwebsite%5D=bbc.co.uk&message%5Bmessage%5D=test%0D%0A&commit=Send+Message
```

Ok so my development environment looks like so

```
 #Mailer Config
 config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
 config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "localhost:3000" }


 config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
 config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 address: "smtp.gmail.com",
 port: 587,
 domain: "gmail.com",
 authentication: "plain",
 enable_starttls_auto: true,
 user_name: "myusername",
 password: "mypassword"
}
```

I have a Contact Controller

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def create
  @message = Message.new(params[:message])
   if @message.valid?
    ContactMailer.send_mail(@message).deliver
    redirect_to(root_path, :notice => "Thanks for your message, I will be in touch soon")
       else
        render :new
      end
    end
  end
```

Mailer

```
class ContactMailer < ActionMailer::Base
 default from: "richlewis14@gmail.com"

 def send_mail(message)
  @message = message
  mail(to: "richlewis14@gmail.com", subject: "Message From Blog Site")
 end
end
```

Mailer text File

```
<p> You have a new Email</p>

<p><%= @contact.name %></p>
<p><%= @contact.email %></p>
<p><%= @contact.website %></p>
<p><%= @contact.message %></p>
```

Message model

```
class Message
 include ActiveModel::Validations
 include ActiveModel::Conversion
 extend ActiveModel::Naming

 attr_accessor :name, :email, :website, :message


def initialize(attributes = {})
 attributes.each do |name, value|
  send("#{name}=", value)
end
end

def persisted?
 false
end
end
```

And finally my routes

```
 #CONTACT FORM
 match 'contact' => 'contact#new', :as => 'contact', :via => :get   
 match 'contact' => 'contact#create', :as => 'contact', :via => :post
```

UPDATE

Ok so despite suggestions below i cannot get my form to post, it keeps rendering a get request, my form looks like so

```
  <div id="contact-form-wrap">
    <form id="contact-form">
     <%= form_for @message, :url => contact_path, :method => :post do |f| %>

      <span class="c-note">Asunt in anim uis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in anim id est laborum. Allamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Aser velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint</span>

    <div class="contact-left">
     <p class="input-block clearfix">
      <%= f.text_field :name, :id => 'contact_name', :placeholder => 'Name' %>
     </p>

    <p class="input-block">
     <%= f.text_field :email, :id => 'contact_email', :placeholder => 'Email' %>
   </p>

    <p class="input-block last">  
     <%= f.text_field :website, :id => 'contact_url', :placeholder => 'Website' %> 
    </p>
  </div><!--end:contact-left-->


 <div class="contact-right">
  <p class="textarea-block">  
  <%= f.text_area :message, :id => 'contact_message', :rows => 6, :placeholder => 'Message' %>                    
  </p>
</div><!--end:contact-right-->

<div class="clear"></div>                            
  <p class="contact-button clearfix">   
    <%= f.submit 'Send Message', :id => 'submit-contact' %>                 
  </p>
  <div class="clear"></div>   
  <% end %>                     
</form>


 </div><!--contact-form-wrap-->
```

Comment: can you receive mail?
just see on the server.

Comment: Can you please write the 'resources :contact' in config/routes.rb.By default rails will handle the request.Please remove the currently added lines in ur config/routes.rb

Comment: tried that but then i get cannot find action index, should i just use only[:new, :create]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it appears that your form (not shown)  is using a GET method, and not matching the create route which is post.   Try changing the Form in your view to use POST.  and that should invoke the create method.   Looking in your logs I am guessing it is executing the new method

change this.

```
 <form id="contact-form">
      <%= form_for @message, :url => contact_path, :method => :post do |f| %>
```

to this

```
  <%= form_for @message, :url => contact_path, :method => :post, :html => {:id => 'contact-form' } do |f| %>
```

and remove the last `</form>` as well.  since the form_for helper will add it as part of the block.  This will remove the nested forms, and should allow you to post / send mail.

Comment: thanks, so ive got this in my form <%= form_for @message, :url => contact_path, :method => 'post' do |f| %>, still not working though, though i have changed valid to save as another answer specified

Comment: I would change back to valid? Since it isn't Database Backed, you don't need to persist it.    You can also add logger statements to to see where it is going. When you submit now, you shouldn't haven't the params in the url

Comment: actually in looking at your code again, I don't see any validations(unless you didn't post them) so you could just try and send the message.  another option would be to include a flash.now on the else with an error message indicating it wasn't sent.

Comment: i havent put any validations in yet, just want the thing to send at the moment, will try flash now

Comment: with no validations. it should show as valid. Have you verified via the logs that you are indeed posting and the create action is being called?  change save back to valid,  and either add the flash or some logger statements in either the contacts controller the contact mailer to see if they are getting called.

Comment: @Doon How will `valid?` work without saving object to database?

Comment: @maximus valid just runs through the validations, has nothing to do with persisting the record.  Persisting the object will cause it to run the validations, and fail if valid? returns false.   A new object will not have any errors on it, since validations haven't run, but once you call #valid? if there are errors then errors  will be populated.   see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Comment: @Doon, you are right. But Why you want to replace `.save` by `.valid?` ?  Since Richlewis has created a model for same purpose.

Comment: @maximus if you look at his model is it not backed by a Database table, and always returns false for persisted? so it is impossible to save it do a database, and save will always return false.

Comment: ok so my form has the method post , :method => 'post'  but when submitting the form it is still performing a get request

Comment: if you view the generated HTML on your form, do you see the post there? post your view code please

Comment: ah thats interesting, the form isnt showing, i have <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">

Comment: show the entire form in your orig question. maybe there is something odd in the form.

Comment: there is your problem. you have a form inside a form.. .

Comment: (slaps head) cant believe that was it